# How to get all the cities for USA in the following dictionary?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have the dictionary below and I would like to get access to all cities for a particular country. So if I select USA below, I want access to Dallas, Houston. For example I have the following function in mind but am not sure how to get all cities for country.

```
-(NSArray*) fetchCitiesFromLocationDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)locationDictionary usingCountry:(NSString *)country
{


}


{
    509f3a914d026b589ba3a090 =     {
        coordinates =         {
            latitude = "29.76429";
            longitude = "-95.3837";
        };
        country = USA;
        id = 509f3a914d026b589ba3a090;
        name = Houston;
        state = Texas;
    };
    509f3b3a4d026b589ba3a091 =     {
        coordinates =         {
            latitude = "3.138722";
            longitude = "101.686849";
        };
        country = Malaysia;
        id = 509f3b3a4d026b589ba3a091;
        name = "Kuala Lumpur";
    };
    509f475b4d026b589ba3a093 =     {
        coordinates =         {
            latitude = "32.803468";
            longitude = "-96.769879";
        };
        country = USA;
        id = 509f475b4d026b589ba3a093;
        name = Dallas;
        state = Texas;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray *cities = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *individualDictionary in dictionary)
{
    if ([[individualDictionary objectForKey:@"country"] isEqualToString:@"USA"])
        [cities addObject:[individualDictionary objectForKey:@"name"]];
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks..im still very new at ios development. thanks much

Answer (score 1):

The way I'm reading this, you can just iterate through the values (using `NSDictionary.allValues`), and if a value.country=USA, then add value.name to your return list (NSMutableArray).

Comment: Not sure but I gave you one :)

Answer (score 1):

both answers are good but id propose a superior one (IMO :D)

1 line

```
id matches = [[dictOfDicts allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"country=='USA'"]];
```

---

working example

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        id dictOfDicts = @{@"1":@{@"country":@"USA", @"name":@"test"}, @"2":@{@"country":@"azUSA", @"name":@"test"}, @"3":@{@"country":@"USA", @"name":@"test"}, @"4":@{@"country":@"adsaUSA", @"name":@"test"}};

        NSLog(@"%@", [[dictOfDicts allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"country=='USA'"]]);
    }
}
```